# How to create regex expression for mach special characters

Tags: c#, regex

I want to create a regex for mach this string value:

```
100[some digits][some digits | some words | @][some digits | some words | @][some digits]
```

example:

```
100[1234567855][1122bb33@@aaa][222@ffff@@@][1234567890]#
```

I used this regex :

```
(100)\[(\d+)\]\[\[(\d+)|(\w+)|(\@)\[(\d+)|(\w+)|(\@)\]\[(\d+)\]#$
```

but It dosent work properly. 
any Ideas?

thanks for any helping...

Comment: what is the environment you are developing in ? is it asp.net ?

Comment: I recommend you to use a custom validator then. Because you can perform the same functionality of the validator without having to go through the regex.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put `\w`, `\d`, `@` inside a   character class to match a word charcater or a digit or an `@` symbol.

```
@"^100\[(\d+)\]\[([\d@\w]+)\]\[([\d@\w]+)\]\[(\d+)\]#$"
```

Since `[` is a special character in regex, you must need to escape that character in-order to match a literal `[` symbol. `[\d@\w]+` matches one or more digit or word character or `@`

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/dV0jK5/2)

Comment: I dosent give the correct match information. I wana each data in [ ] be in seprate  gorup.

Comment: just surround the character class by capturing group. See my update.

Answer (score 1):

Your regex is wrong in some places.

```
(100)\[(\d+)\]\[\[(\d+)|(\w+)|(\@)\[(\d+)|(\w+)|(\@)\]\[(\d+)\]#$
                ^^               ^^                ^
                 1               23                4
```

- 1: Duplicate \[
- 2: Missing +
- 3: Missing \]
- 4: Missing +

Try:

```
(100)\[(\d+)\]\[((\d)|(\w)|(\@))+\]\[((\d)|(\w)|(\@))+\]\[(\d+)\]#$
```

Answer (score 0):

```
^(100)\[([^\]]*)\]\[([^\]]*)\]\[([^\]]*)\]\[([^\]]*)\]#$
```

You can use this instead.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/vD5iH9/58

You can improve your regex by including all in character class.

```
^(100)\[(\d+)\]\[([\da-zA-Z@]+)\]\[([\da-zA-Z@]+)\]\[(\d+)\]#$
```

You were capturing `(\d+)|(\w+)|(\@)` whereas you have `@` twice or thrice in your test string.

Answer (score 0):

try this 
this will make sure that there is a 100 followed by the expression you want .

^      : beginning of expression.

[^100] : starts with a 100

```
^(.?$|[^100]\[([^\]]*)\]\[([^\]]*)\]\[([^\]]*)\]\[([^\]]*)\])#
```

Comment: Review comment: you should give some context to your answers. Explain them a little on how they works.